# How to read action method's attributes in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Based on [this article](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2014/dependency-injection-in-attributes-dont-do-it/) I'm trying to create an `IActionFilter` implementation for ASP.NET Core that can process attributes that are marked on the controller and the controller's action. Although reading the controller's attributes is easy, I'm unable to find a way to read the attributes defined on the action method.

Here's the code I have right now:

```
public sealed class ActionFilterDispatcher : IActionFilter
{
    private readonly Func<Type, IEnumerable> container;

    public ActionFilterDispatcher(Func<Type, IEnumerable> container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var attributes = context.Controller.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(true);

        attributes =
            attributes.Append(/* how to read attributes from action method? */);

        foreach (var attribute in attributes)
        {
            Type filterType = typeof(IActionFilter<>)
                .MakeGenericType(attribute.GetType());
            IEnumerable filters = this.container.Invoke(filterType);

            foreach (dynamic actionFilter in filters)
            {
                actionFilter.OnActionExecuting((dynamic)attribute, context);
            }
        }
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

My question is: how do I read the action method's attributes in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Comment: You'd get the `MemberInfo` for whatever method you're interested in using the reflection API, then use `GetCustomAttributes` on that. Hopefully I'm not misunderstanding the question

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You can access the `MethodInfo` of the action through the [`ControllerActionDescriptor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllers.controlleractiondescriptor) class:

```
public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
{
    if (context.ActionDescriptor is ControllerActionDescriptor descriptor)
    {
        var actionAttributes =
           descriptor.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(inherit: true);
    }
}
```

The MVC 5 [`ActionDescriptor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actiondescriptor(v=vs.118).aspx) class used to implement the `ICustomAttributeProvider` interface which gave access to the attributes. For some reason this was removed in the ASP.NET Core MVC [`ActionDescriptor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.abstractions.actiondescriptor) class.

Comment: How can I do that in asp.net mvc 6

Comment: This is about MVC 6 (or Core 1.0).

Comment: My mistake I did not look clearly. Could you check my answer is right or not? I just find a way to get attribute and will post it.

Comment: It can also be useful to check the controllerActionDescriptor.ControllerTypeInfo.GetCustomAttributes() to get attributes that have been set on the controller instead of the method as well.

Comment: You can use pattern matching for this code: `if (context.ActionDescriptor is ControllerActionDescriptor controllerActionDescriptor)`

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the answer for MVC 5 while you were at it!

Answer (score 45):

Invoking `GetCustomAttributes` on a method and/or class is **slow**(er). You should **not** invoke `GetCustomAttributes` every request since .net core 2.2, which @Henk Mollema is suggesting. (There is one exception which I will explain later)

Instead, on application startup time, the asp.net core framework will invoke `GetCustomAttributes` on the action method and controller for you and store the result in the [`EndPoint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.endpoint?view=aspnetcore-2.2) [metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.endpoint.metadata?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

You can then access this metadata in your asp.net core filters via the [`EndpointMetadata` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.abstractions.actiondescriptor.endpointmetadata?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Abstractions_ActionDescriptor_EndpointMetadata) of the [`ActionDescriptor` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.abstractions.actiondescriptor?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

```
public class CustomFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        // Get attributes on the executing action method and it's defining controller class
        var attributes = context.ActionDescriptor.EndpointMetadata.OfType<MyCustomAttribute>();
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

If you do not have access to the `ActionDescriptor` (for example: because you are operating from a Middleware instead of an filter) **from asp.net core 3.0** you can use the [`GetEndpoint` extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.endpointhttpcontextextensions.getendpoint?view=aspnetcore-3.1) to access it's [`Metadata`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.endpoint.metadata?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_Endpoint_Metadata).
For more info see [this](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/7795) github issue.

```
public class CustomMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;

    public CustomMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        // Get the enpoint which is executing (asp.net core 3.0 only)
        var executingEnpoint = context.GetEndpoint();

        // Get attributes on the executing action method and it's defining controller class
        var attributes = executingEnpoint.Metadata.OfType<MyCustomAttribute>();

        await next(context);

        // Get the enpoint which was executed (asp.net core 2.2 possible after call to await next(context))
        var executingEnpoint2 = context.GetEndpoint();

        // Get attributes on the executing action method and it's defining controller class
        var attributes2 = executingEnpoint.Metadata.OfType<MyCustomAttribute>();
    }
}
```

Like stated above, Endpoint Metadata contains the attributes for the action method and its defining controller class. This means that if you would want to explicitly IGNORE the attributes applied on either the controller class or the action method, you have to use `GetCustomAttributes`. This is almost never the case in asp.net core.

Comment: This should be the correct answer if you are using endpoint routing with ASP.NET Core 3.0 or later

Comment: Great answer, I had to upgrade to 3.1 but it was worth it.

Comment: `OfType<MyCustomAttribute>` need `using System.Linq`

Answer (score 8):

My custom attribute is inherit from ActionFilterAttribute. I put it on my controller but there is one action do not need it. I want to use `AllowAnonymous` attribute to ignore that but it not work. So I add this snippet in my custom attribute to find the `AllowAnonymous` and skip it. You can get other in the for loop.

```
    public class PermissionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            foreach (var filterDescriptors in context.ActionDescriptor.FilterDescriptors)
            {
                if (filterDescriptors.Filter.GetType() == typeof(AllowAnonymousFilter))
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The `FilterDescriptors` property only works if your custom attribute actually is an [MVC Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters). If you have a custom [passive attribute](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/13/passive-attributes/) applied to your action, then obviously your solution will not work.

Answer (score 7):

I created an extension method that mimics the original `GetCustomAttributes` based in Henk Mollema's solution.

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> GetCustomAttributes<T>(this Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Abstractions.ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) where T : Attribute
    {
        var controllerActionDescriptor = actionDescriptor as ControllerActionDescriptor;
        if (controllerActionDescriptor != null)
        {
            return controllerActionDescriptor.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes<T>();
        }

        return Enumerable.Empty<T>();
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Works fine in combination with NuGet package System.Reflection.Extensions and a using to System.Reflection

Answer (score 0):

As answered by [Henk Mollena](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1823494/henk-mollema)

```
public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
{
    var controllerActionDescriptor = context.ActionDescriptor as ControllerActionDescriptor;
    if (controllerActionDescriptor != null)
    {
        var controllerAttributes = controllerActionDescriptor
                               .MethodInfo
                               .GetCustomAttributes(inherit: true);
    }
}
```

is the correct way if you want to check the presence of an attribute **applied to an action**.

I just want to add to his answer in case if you want to check the presence of an attribute **applied to the controller**

```
public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
{
    var controllerActionDescriptor = context.ActionDescriptor as ControllerActionDescriptor;
    if (controllerActionDescriptor != null)
    {
        var actionAttributes = controllerActionDescriptor.ControllerTypeInfo.GetCustomAttributes(inherit: true);
    }
}
```

Also you can use the overloaded function of the GetCustomAttributes functions to get your specific attribute(s)

```
var specificAttribute = GetCustomAttributes(typeof(YourSpecificAttribute), true).FirstOrDefault()
```