# Override global action filter in controller/action in ASP.NET Core MVC 1.0.1 (ASP.NET Core 1.1)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am building a ASP.NET Core MVC application and am trying to create a global action filter that logs how much time is spent executing an action (it should only log if spent time is above some threshold). I have succesfully done this but now I want to be able to say that a single action or a single controller should have a different threshold. When I try this, my action filter is applied twice(which is not what I want) but with the correct two different thresholds.

I have tried quite a few things and searched around. In an MVC 3 and an MVC 4 project I have successfully done this using RegisterGlobalFilters() in Global.asax and it automatically overrides the global one when I used the attribute on a controller/action. I have also tried the approach listed in this post, without luck:

[Override global authorize filter in ASP.NET Core MVC 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35825021/override-global-authorize-filter-in-asp-net-core-mvc-1-0)

My code for my ActionFilterAttribute:

```
public class PerformanceLoggingAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public int ExpectedMax = -1; // Log everything unless this is explicitly set
    private Stopwatch sw;

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        sw.Stop();
        if (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds >= ExpectedMax)
        {
            // Log here
        }
    }

    //public override Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    //{
    //    // If there is another performance filter, do nothing
    //    if (context.Filters.Any(item => item is PerformanceLoggingAttribute && item != this))
    //    {
    //        return Task.FromResult(0);
    //    }
    //    return base.OnActionExecutionAsync(context, next);
    //}
}
```

I am applying this global filter in my Startup.cs:

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                if (_env.IsProduction()) options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
                //options.Filters.Add(new PerformanceLoggingFilter() { ExpectedMax = 1 }); // Add Performance Logging filter
                options.Filters.Add(new PerformanceLoggingAttribute() { ExpectedMax = 1 }); // Add Performance Logging filter
            });
```

And in my controller I am applying the attribute:

```
//[TypeFilter(typeof(PerformanceLoggingFilter))]
[PerformanceLogging(ExpectedMax = 2)]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var vm = _performanceBuilder.BuildPerformanceViewModel();
    return View(vm);
}
```

As you can tell from the code snippets above I have tried the OnActionExecutionAsync approach and I have also tried a IActionFilter instead and using [TypeFilter(typeof(PerformanceLoggingFilter))] on actions, but no luck.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working thanks to @Set's answer above in combination with this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36932793/5762645

I ended up with a global action that is applied to all actions and then having a simple ExpectedMaxAttribute that I put on actions where the threshold should be different. In the OnActionExecuted of my global action filter, I then check if the action in question has the ExpectedMaxAttribute attached to it and then read the ExpectedMax from that. Below is my attribute:

```
public class PerformanceLoggingExpectedMaxAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public int ExpectedMax = -1;
}
```

And the OnActionExecuted part that I added to my ActionFilter:

```
 public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
 {
     sw.Stop();
     foreach (var filterDescriptor in context.ActionDescriptor.FilterDescriptors)
     {
         if (filterDescriptor.Filter is PerformanceLoggingExpectedMaxAttribute)
         {
             var expectedMaxAttribute = filterDescriptor.Filter as PerformanceLoggingExpectedMaxAttribute;
             if (expectedMaxAttribute != null) ExpectedMax = expectedMaxAttribute.ExpectedMax;
             break;
         }
     }
     if (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds >= ExpectedMax)
     {
         _logger.LogInformation("Test log from PerformanceLoggingActionFilter");
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

May suggest you a bit different implementation of what you try to achieve by using one action filter and additional custom attribute:

- create a new simple attribute (let's name it `ExpectedMaxAttribute`), that just holds the `ExpectedMax` value. Apply this attribute to controller's actions with different values.
- keep your `PerformanceLogging` action filter as global, but modify implementation. On `OnActionExecuted` method check if controller's action has `ExpectedMaxAttribute`. If yes, then read `ExpectedMax` value from attribute, otherwise use the default value from the action filter.

---

Also, I recommend you to rename action filter accordingly to convention naming something like `PerformanceLoggingActionFilter`.

Comment: Your answer led me on the right path. I have posted my solution as an answer. Thanks!