# descriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName in AspNetCore.Mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm building an ASP.NET Core 2.0 Web Application. In ASP.NET WEB I used System.Web.Mvc where I had the following line to get the ControllerName:

```
descriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName
```

In ASP.NET Core 2.0 this does not work I get the error:

> Error CS1061  'ActionDescriptor' does not contain a definition for
>   'ControllerDescriptor' and no extension method 'ControllerDescriptor'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'ActionDescriptor'

In ASP.NET Core 2.0 I can't find an alternative to get the ControllerName.
Does anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You'll have to cast the `ActionDescriptor` instance to a [`ControllerActionDescriptor`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/7b2a4ff46583f9897041fbd8d1463be068ddc287/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Controllers/ControllerActionDescriptor.cs) instance in order to get access to the `ControllerName` property:

```
var controllerActionDescriptor = context.ActionDescriptor as ControllerActionDescriptor;
if (controllerActionDescriptor != null)
{
    var controllerName = controllerActionDescriptor.ControllerName;
}
```

Related: [How to read action method's attributes in ASP.NET Core MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31874733/)