# Web API: how to read action attribute and parameters from HttpContext

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, httpcontext, actioncontext, routedata

In regular class, I need to read following from the `HttpContext`:

1. Controller and action name
2. Action's attribute (I could get that through `HttpActionContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<type>()`  but here I don't have `HttpActionContext` - I only have `HttpContext`)
3. Read argument (like `actionContext.ActionArguments["paramName"]`, but again - I only have a `HttpContext`)

It's not an action filter and not a controller class. But, I can access `HttpContext`.

Comment: Have you checked under HttpContext.Current.Request.Form?

Comment: ya, I can not find the value (posted value) that I could see under `actionContext.ActionArguments["paramName"]`.

Answer (score 9):

> From asp.net core 3.0 https://stackoverflow.com/a/60602828/10612695

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    // Get the enpoint which is executing (asp.net core 3.0 only)
    var executingEnpoint = context.GetEndpoint();

    // Get attributes on the executing action method and it's defining controller class
    var attributes = executingEnpoint.Metadata.OfType<MyCustomAttribute>();

    await next(context);

    // Get the enpoint which was executed (asp.net core 2.2 possible after call to await next(context))
    var executingEnpoint2 = context.GetEndpoint();

    // Get attributes on the executing action method and it's defining controller class
    var attributes2 = executingEnpoint.Metadata.OfType<MyCustomAttribute>();
}
```